# program can't find next button

Tags: python, selenium, element

I am writing a unit test program to test my site's links and return an ok if everything is working. One problem I keep running into is that it's not very consistent one run it will find all specific elements then the next it can't. I feel like it could be due to my internet connection because when I connect to my phone hotspot it runs much smoother. But I can't rely on this program for my website testing if it's not consistent with its results. Right now everything is running smoothly except finding this one element next_arrow. I am using the xpath for the button but it continues to say unable to locate. I also used the xpath in a separate program just to really see if it wasn't working and program 2 found the element and clicked on it repeatedly. Maybe I've been looking at it for too long any help would be great.

```
def test_e_transparency_page(self):
        self.posts = ['//*[@id="pgi86feccece3844ba09f80aa6696eb037f_0"]',
        '//*[@id="pgibb0246bf32f6468189670ff4c02f48d6_1"]', '//*[@id="pgi561b043aafbf428aa532ca1212803c15_2"]']
        self.compare = ["//span[contains(text(),'what you should know about your CBD oil')]", "//span[contains(text(),'Essential Oil Facts')]",
                                "//span[contains(text(),'the benefits of natural butters & oils')]"]
        self.intext = ["what you should know about your CBD oil", "Essential Oil Facts",
        "the benefits of natural butters & oils", "Hemp Facts Topics"]
        self.exits = ["//*[@id='comp-jvfpiv1wsvgcontent']",
        "//*[@id='comp-jvfii91usvgcontent']", "//*[@id='comp-jvfpdcbwsvgcontent']"]
        self.errormsgs = ["Our Farms Error","Essiental Oil Benifits","Butters and Oils"]
        self.tran.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        assert "Transparency | Black Hemp Family" in self.driver.title, "Transparency Button Link Error"
        time.sleep(5)
        next_arrow = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
        for (post, c, text, exit_button, error) in zip(self.posts, self.compare, self.intext, self.exits, self.errormsgs):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(post).click()
            time.sleep(3)
            title = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(c)
            time.sleep(1)
            assert text in title.text, error
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(exit_button).click()
            time.sleep(3)
            next_arrow.click()

        cbd_info = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='pgi6faab6bad5984f57a41cfd82c3623871_3']").click()
        time.sleep(3)
        assert self.intext[3] in self.driver.title, "CBD Info Link Error"
```

Comment: i can post the entire code if needed

Comment: Try not to use time.sleep() instead use webdriver waits.

Comment: When I use webdriver wait it doesn't work it still just runs past it

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this for your loop?

```
for (post, c, text, exit_button, error) in zip(self.posts, self.compare, self.intext, self.exits, self.errormsgs):
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(post).click()
time.sleep(3)
title = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(c)
time.sleep(1)
assert text in title.text, error
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(exit_button).click()
time.sleep(3)
next_arrow = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
if next_arrow:
    next_arrow.click()
```